# Pick a random index then get attributes from that index (Jmeter)

Tags: java, arrays, jmeter

I have an `array`:

```
WeaponInventory:[
     {
           name: sword,
           damage: 400,
           price:20  
     },
     {
           name: bow_and_arrow,
           damage: 150,
           price:10   
     },
     {
           name: axe,
           damage: 250,
           price:15 
     }
]
```

I am picking one random item from my inventory by using this:

```
Thread Group
   Get Weapon Inventory (which returns the json array i stated above)
      Json Extractor (right now im getting by name)
```

When I get a `name` (using Match  No. 0 from the `Json Extractor`), I also want to get the `damage` and `price` of that item. Do I need to extract the entire array and just process it in a post processor or is there a way to handle it using `json` extractors. Any heads up would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **"-1" as Match No.** means extract all results, they will be named as _N.
Use a Debug Sampler to fetch the desired fields further.